# Deriving ideal gas law from Boyle and Charles

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, ideal-gas

My textbook states

> Notice that since $PV = \text{constant}$ and $\frac{V}{T} = \text{constant}$ for a given
> quantity of gas, then $\frac{PV}{T}$ should also be a constant.

I tried to prove this, but no success:
$$PV = a$$
$$\frac{V}{T} = b$$

$$\frac{PV^2}{T} = ab$$
$$PT = \frac{a}{b}$$

But I am not able to cook up $\frac{PV}{T}$... Any help?

Comment: Related in ChemSE: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/127772/32355

Answer (score 13):

This formulation of [Boyle's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyle%27s_law)
$$PV=\text{const}$$
is very misunderstandable.
Actually the constant on the right side
is only meant to be independent of $P$ and $V$.
But it may still depend on other parameters,
like $T$ (temperature) and $N$ (number of molecules).
So a better way to write this law is
$$PV=a(T,N) \tag{1}$$
where $a(T,N)$ is some unknown function of $T$ and $N$.

Likewise this formulation of [Charles's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles%27s_law)
$$\frac{V}{T}=\text{const}$$
is misunderstandable in the same way.
A better way to write it is
$$\frac{V}{T}=b(P,N) \tag{2}$$
where $b(P,N)$ is some unknown function of $P$ and $N$.

Now we can divide equation (1) by $T$
and multiply equation (2) by $P$ to get
$$\frac{PV}{T} = \frac{a(T,N)}{T} = P\ b(P,N).$$
The only way for this to hold true while varying $P$ and $T$
is that $\frac{a(T,N)}{T}$ is independent of $T$,
and $P\ b(P,N)$ is independent of $P$.
Hence it only depends on $N$, and we can call this function $c(N)$.

So finally we arrived at the [combined gas law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law#Combined_gas_law)
$$\frac{PV}{T}=c(N) \tag{3}$$
where $c(N)$ is some unknown function of $N$ only.

Comment: The missing step between $(2)$ and $(3)$ is dividing $(1)$ by $T$ and multiplying $(2)$ by $P$ to get $\frac{PV}{T} = \frac{a(T,N)}{T} = P*b(P,N)$. The only way for this to hold true while varying $P$ and $T$ is if they cancel both out, meaning $a(T,N) = T*c(N)$ and $b(P,N) = \frac{c(N)}{P}$

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft You're right. Thanks for filling the gap in the logic.

Answer (score 5):

$PV$ is constant for fixed $T$, and $V/T$ is constant for fixed $P$. Hence

$PV=f(T)$ and $V/T=g(P)$.

From these we can write

$V=f(T)/P=T\times g(P)$.

This implies that

$f(T)=kT$ and $g(P)=k/P$    for some constant $k$.

Hence $PV/T = k$ (constant, actually $nR$) is the required answer.

Comment: Nice! Pretty sure you meant $g(P) = k/P$ in the last but one line...

Comment: Of course I did ;) Thanks - fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

You can't derive it like that because the proportionality relations hold only when the third parameter is kept constant.

---

However, you can derive the ideal gas law by noting that for high temperature,  we get a limit as shown below:

$$ \lim_{ p \to 0 } p \overline{V} = f(T)$$

So, the limit of the product as pressure drops to zero is a unique function $ f(T)$ for all gases independent of the substance used. We can use this to define the linear kelvin scale. Using the triple point of water and absolute zero as our reference,

$$ f(T) = \frac{f(T_{trip-point})}{273.16K} T$$

Where $f(T_{trip-point})$ is the value of the limit at the triple point, using this and our first equation, we can write,

$$ \lim_{ p \to 0} p \overline{V} =  \frac{f(T_{trip-point})}{273.16K} T$$

and now, the universal gas constant is defined as follows:

$$ R =  \frac{f(T_{trip-point})}{273.16K}$$

Which leads us to:

$$ \lim_{ p \to 0} p \overline{V}  = RT$$

Now, we call an ideal gas is one which obeys the above relation even when the limit is not there.

$$ p \overline{V} = RT$$

---

Reference: [from 10:46 of this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDqx8Zv1rRo&list=PLA62087102CC93765&index=2&ab_channel=MITOpenCourseWare)

Comment: pretty sure you meant `... even when the limit is there.` in the last line. thank you for pointing me to that mit course XD

Comment: Ahhh I fixed it now :D Btw are you Indian? If so check out my profile , you may find something there :D

Answer (score 0):

Boyle’s Law: V ∝ (1/P) (constant T, n)

Charles’s Law: V ∝ T (constant P, n)

Avogadro’s Hypothesis: V ∝ n (constant T, P)

The combination of the three laws for ideal gases yields to

V ∝ nT/P

you can pass from proportionality to equality by introducing a constant R

$V =R nT/P$

and so you have that $PV/T = Rn$

Comment: If you can just combine the proportionalities like that, then why didn't op's method work?